# Proving that $H_e$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, topological-groups

I'm having some trouble understanding the proof for the following proposition:

> Let $G$ be a topological group, $H$ be a normal subgroup and $H_e$ be the connected component of $e$ with respect to $H$. Then $H_e$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

They started by proving that, for any $g\in G, gH_eg^{-1}\subseteq H_e$, but then the proof ended there. The author didn't prove that $H_e$ is a group in the first place, maybe because it's trivial, but either way I can't figure out how to prove this.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cannot make a comment, I’ll give you a hint as an answer:

Continuous images of connected sets are connected and the group multiplication and inversion are continuous maps.

Comment: I still don't understand how that proves that $H_e$ is a group

Comment: You need to show that the identity component is closed under multiplication and inversion, i.e. if you multiply two elements from the identity component, you get a result in the identity component. And the same for inverting an element. Can you see on which connected component you will end up?

Comment: Because inversion is a homeomorphism, for any $x \in H_e$, $x^{-1}$ and $e^{-1} = e$ will be in the same connected component, this $x^{-1} \in H_e$. Is this it?

Comment: That’s correct :)

Comment: but how do you prove the same for multiplication? Is it true that $H_e \times H_e$ is the connected component of $(e,e)$ in $G\times G$?

Comment: Here you use that the product of connected spaces is connected. So now you have all the ingredients and you need to put them together.

Comment: I think I got it now, thank you